# setText(getString(R.strings.whatever) or setText(R.strings.whatever)?

Tags: android

Both work, obviously if you start concatenating you'll need get string in order to avoid displaying an int.

Question: which is the most 'elegant' or 'recommended' to use?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second approach is more elegant, since internally, the `TextView` (or whatever `View`-class) will do the job of getting the String for your specified resource.

Letting components do the internal work is always preferred. Also, it is shorter and more readable.

---

About the internals I talked about: If you have a look at Androids source-code, you can see that the `setText(int)`-method of `TextView` [is implemented like this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setText%28int%29):

```
public final void setText(int resid) {
  setText(getContext().getResources().getText(resid));
}
```

So, it internally uses the `Context`-class to get the string from the resource-id. Now, if you look at the `getText()`-method (which also comes from the `Context`-class), you can see that it [is implemented the same way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/content/Context.java#Context.getString%28int%29):

```
public final String getString(int resId) {
  return getResources().getString(resId);
}
```

So for performance or reliability reasons, it makes no difference. Still, it is shorter and more readable.

Comment: @Shamrflow I updated the answer with some code from the Android source to show, that it is implemented the same way. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you Lukas, even better. I've noticed it's also true for setTitle and setMessage in the AlertBuilder, and a few other classes. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the API provides a method to pass Resource String ID, It seems to be logical to prefer using this. You could actually check the working of setText(resourceid) to see beneath the hood, but setText(R.strings.whatever) is definitely recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
yourEditText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.mytext));
```

because you need get the resource context, after get the string.