# setText fails to show a number as text in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-resources

I have 4 buttons and 1 TextView. I want each of the buttons to add or subtract a different amount from the value (parsed to int) in the TextView. When I click on one of the buttons it throws fatal errors (listed below). I've searched some other Stackoverflow discussions and nothing seems to be working. Here is my current activity:

```
public class PaydownSnowball extends Activity {
int aAmt;
String debtExtraPayment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.snowball);

    final Button plusTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonp10);
    final Button plusFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonp5);
    final Button minusFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonm5);
    final Button minusTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonm10);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("chaosdatasnowball", 0);
    debtExtraPayment = sharedPref.getString("debtExtraPayment", null);
    debtExtraPayment ="0";
    TextView addAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispAddAmt);
    addAmount.setText(debtExtraPayment);
    aAmt = Integer.parseInt(debtExtraPayment);


    plusTen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          aAmt = aAmt + 10;
          TextView addAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispAddAmt);
          addAmount.setText(aAmt);
        }
      });
    plusFive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          aAmt = aAmt + 5;
          TextView addAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispAddAmt);
          addAmount.setText(aAmt);
        }
      });
    minusTen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          aAmt = aAmt - 10;
          TextView addAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispAddAmt);
          addAmount.setText(aAmt);
        }
      });
    minusFive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          aAmt = aAmt - 5;
          TextView addAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dispAddAmt);
          addAmount.setText(aAmt);
        }
      });


    debtExtraPayment = String.valueOf(aAmt);
    addAmount.setText(debtExtraPayment);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("debtExtraPayment", debtExtraPayment).commit();
}
```

Here are the logcats that occur on click of the plusFive button:

```
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at biz.midl.debtsnowball.PaydownSnowball$2.onClick(PaydownSnowball.java:47)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-09 15:15:57.907: E/AndroidRuntime(695):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 15:15:59.467: I/Process(695): Sending signal. PID: 695 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with lines like this

```
addAmount.setText(aAmt);
```

where `aAmt` is an `int`. This looks for a `resource` with the `id` of whatever `aAmt` is. You need to cast it to a `String` first like

```
addAmount.setText(String.valueOf(aAmt));
```

There are overloaded `setText()` methods. [See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int))

[This post goes into some more detail as to how this actually works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120907/1724097)

Comment: OK, please see the link to the docs above so you understand the difference and why this is.

Comment: or `addAmount.setText("" + aAmt);`

Comment: I am reading them over - thank you very much - @popovitisj - thank you as well!

Comment: Yes, there are different ways to accomplish this. The point is that it needs to be a `String` to achieve the goal here. I usually use the way I posted because I think it is more explicit of what is happening but there are several ways to make it happen

Answer (score 1):

You can Try one of these two:

1. `addAmount.setText("" + aAmt);`
2. `addAmount.setText(String.valueOf(aAmt));`

you'll get a String result without any error.