# 1 error wont let my code compile

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and I am trying to make an app that splits a bill between people. But something about my integers are wrong. I know this because in my logcat it says "Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:  ""

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public double x;
public double y;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Button
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    //EditText
    EditText nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText cob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


    //Getting the strings
    try{
        x = Double.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException) {
        x = 0;
    }

    try{
        y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException) {
        y = 0;
    }

    String textX = nop.getText().toString();
// if variable contains valid number:
    if (textX != null && textX.length() > 0)
        x = Double.valueOf();   // exception thrown by method
    else
        x = 0;

    //TextView
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             double z = x / y;
            tv.setText((int) z);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
08-19 07:30:28.452  16070-16070/com.elie.billsplitter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.elie.billsplitter, PID: 16070
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elie.billsplitter/com.elie.billsplitter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
            at com.elie.billsplitter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Please add the error you experience..

Comment: Post the error you're getting

Comment: Post example with wrong integers

Comment: Also why  are you using double values for x, y, z(bad variable names, you should consider using better ones) but  parsing the values out via Integer    `x = Integer.parseInt(nop.getText().toString());`. Just parse them out as doubles  `x = Double.parseDouble(nop.getText().toString());`.

Comment: double z = x / y; should be  double z = (double) x / y;

Comment: One problem is that you are using the [wrong setText() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883815/settext-fails-to-show-a-number-as-text-in-a-textview/19883845#19883845)

Comment: What integer value would you expect `""` to represent?

Comment: @David i dont have "" in my code but it still gives me that error

Comment: @Asm: It's not a hard-coded value, it's a runtime value.  `getText()` returns a string.  In this case, it's returning the string `""`.  Which can't be converted to a numeric value because it isn't a number.

Comment: @David So how can i make return an actual string

Comment: @Asm: `""` *is* an "actual string".  It's just a string with no characters in it.  As for returning a *different* string, I imagine those `nop` and `cob` objects would need "actual strings" to return.  An `EditText` object sounds like a UI input element.  So... put a number in that UI element?  Currently your code assumes that a user-input string will be a number.  That assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @David But the user input string should be a number shouldn't it. Since you cant do math with words.

Comment: @Asm: Telling your users to use the program properly isn't really an ideal solution.  Checking the input to see if it's a number and showing a message if it isn't might be a bit better.

Comment: @David I like your idea but I'm not sure how to do it. Could you make an answer and show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elie.billsplitter/com.elie.billsplitter.MainActivity}: **java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""**

The error is in this piece of code

```
//Getting the strings
x = Integer.parseInt(nop.getText().toString());
y = Integer.parseInt(cob.getText().toString());
```

**Why?** 
`nop.getText().toString().equals("")` or `cob.getText().toString().equals("")`.

**How to avoid?** 
You must be sure you get a valid `String` from this `EditText` because if them are empty or does not contain an equivaloent `double` `String` you will have a `NumberFormatException`.

**Solution?**
Best ways will be:

- adding a validation to `EditText` to get only valid `String`s.
- Convert the value if `NumberFormatException` is thrown.

```
try{
    x = Double.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    x = 0;
}

try{
    y = Double.valueOf(cop.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    y = 1; // division / 0 will throw NaN
}
```

**ADD-ON:**
*Why I dont use `Integer.parseInt()`??*
 
If you create `double`s you cannot parse `int`s because you will lose accuracy, and, for example in java `(int) 1 / (int) 3 = 0` or `(int) 10 / (int) 3 = 3` so use [Double::valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

```
x = Double.valueOf(nop.getText().toString());
y = Double.valueOf(cob.getText().toString());
```

Comment: **first** of all, [don't modify original code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169052/guidance-to-avoid-chameleon-behavior), **second**, read carefully the answer: you applied 2 of the techniques I posted in original answer so **please delete second `x` assignment** from `String textX = nop.getText().toString();` to `x = 0`.

Comment: Great to hear this @Asm. As this is your first queston, you must know that if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course there is no obligation to do this.

Comment: One more question (that im pretty sure you can answer) @Jordi why is it always giving me 0.0 when i divide

Comment: I can bet is last line: `tv.setText((int) z);` you don't have to cast to int, as you can read in my answer int's in java are natural numbers, no decimals... so... change it to `tv.setText(z);` or `tv.setText(String.valueOf(z));` if conversion gives you problems.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm wasting your time but it didn't work.

Comment: you know how to [debug apps](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-debug-launch.htm)? this is what you need.... if not, dont hesitate to ask a new question, but please, don't modify this, and don't paste all your code, just **important parts**

Comment: I am new to programming and I don't paste my code but I make small modifications

Comment: avoid to modify code provided in questions with answers because this confuses, as I tell you, please debug your app to see values in `x`, `y` and `z` and if you don't solve **post a new question**

Comment: Could you please just help me with this one question because I've been waiting three days and now I finally found an answer

Comment: I'm sorry but with provided info I can't know what is going on.... that's why I tell you to debug.... or post a new question because your problem, now is another...