# setText Method Crashes Android App

Tags: android, reference, crash, textview, settext

I'm writing an android app that needs to use setText() on a TextView, which should be easy, but every time, the app crashes right when it gets to the method.  I have another app that I've coded exactly the same, as far as I can tell, (other than variable names of course) which works.  My best guess is that it has something to do with references, but I've checked everything there that I know how to check.

Here's my XML layout code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yay!" />
```

And my Java Activity code:

```
package com.example.campgames;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView test;
CheckBox lowerElem;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    test=(android.widget.TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    lowerElem=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.lower_elem);

}

public void click(View view){
    test.setText(R.string.inside);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Thanks for your help, and let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.  First time poster!

Comment: possible duplicate of [setText(getString(R.strings.whatever) or setText(R.strings.whatever)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120867/settextgetstringr-strings-whatever-or-settextr-strings-whatever)

Comment: I dont think "test.setText(R.string.inside)" is the actual cause of crash.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1):

Try using

`String textToSet = (String) yourContext.getResources().getText(R.string.inside);
test.setText(textToSet);`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

public void click(View view){
   test.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.inside));

}

instead of

test.setText(R.string.inside);

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
 public void click(View view){
        test.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.inside));
    }
```

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 test.setText(getResources().getString(R.String.mycar));
```

instead of

```
test.setText(R.string.inside);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from click() method.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
```

Comment: Its not necessary to remove it. It will not crash your app.